# Connecting Windows PCs with Ethernet and Switches Without Internet Access IPs Being Overridden?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, ip-address

I have seven computers located far away from the router. I am using them as a part of a render farm, so they all access a central machine (the render server) and read files from it, perform computations, and write output results back to it. They communicate with the render server using a python script where each machine is addressed directly by its private IP using a TCP handler. I've been doing this for the past few months purely over wi-fi, but the reading/writing parts are very slow since it involves a lot of data transfer and it all falls apart the moment the router or ISP has issues, which happened frequently.

To alleviate these problems, I decided to connect them all together using ethernet cables and switches. I used the technique presented [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/connect-two-windows-computer-on-lan/) to connect them all directly so that they do not depend on a wi-fi connection. All render clients have their wi-fi turned off, so they only communicate to the render server over the cables and no render client has internet access.

In order to set this up, I assigned each machines the IP addresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, ... 192.168.0.7, all with subnet masks of 255.255.255.0 and an "Interface Metric" of 20. At the moment, this seems to be working great.

What I don't understand is the following; if I have given each of these seven computers these private IP addresses and they are completely isolated from the router, what stops the router from assigning one of those private IP addresses to another wi-fi device that joins the network later on? The reason this concerns me is because the render server is connected to the router as well as all the render clients, and it sends commands directly to the render clients directly by its IP address. If another device were to join the wi-fi network and be assigned one of the IPs of a render client, I have no idea how the operating system would handle that (which device would my Python script send the command to?).

**I don't know if this will actually be a problem, but I am curious. Is it possible for the router to assign a new wi-fi device one of the render-client's IP addresses? If so, how will Windows OS handle that when running programs designed to send messages directly to certain IPs? If not, how does it know to prevent that?**

The Python script is using the MyTCPHandler example presented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) to communicate with the render clients.

Answer (score 1):

The IP addresses you assign should be outside of the DHCP range your router picks IPs to assign from.

Alternatively you could give your render farm computers an IP on a different subnet so they are on their own small network.

Comment: So I assume my router is using 255.255.255.0 as its default subnet? Also, do you know what would happen in the scenario when the router assigns a duplicate IP (how does Windows handle that)?

Comment: That is a typical default so probably.  As far as having duplicate IPs on the network, you just end up with random/strange network errors as packets might get randomly routed to either device.  I think Windows will attempt to warn you if there is a duplicate IP situation, but that is all it does afaik.